What is the expiration date of an international health certificate for travel with dogs from the USA to Venezuela?
We are traveling from the USA to Venezuela with our two small dogs for 2 months, we want to make sure that we will be ok coming back to the USA. We don't see any expiration date on the health certificate the vet provided.

I’m voting to close this question because it's more suited for Travel SE

The requirements for taking a dog to Venezuela can be found at
Pet Travel From the United States to Venezuela.
The health certificate required is Veterinary Health Certificate for Export of Dogs and Cats from the United States to Venezuela.
Your health certificate should appear very similar to this — if not, there may be a problem. It states "This certificate is valid for 14 days after issuance" and it does also state that the animal must be examined "within 10 days of departure from the United States."
The health certificate is only valid for travel from the USA to Venezuela. The re-entry requirements for the USA are generally very simple. They may require evaluation by a veterinarian in Venezuela before the return journey. Each state varies somewhat so you need to check your specific state requirements. Your vet should be able to help you to understand your state's requirements.
